# Nested split gutters using Susy's span functions

Tags: susy, susy-sass

Does Susy have a built in way to account for children of parents with split gutters using the `span` function rather than the mixin? The child here ends up gutter short (as expected):

```
$susy: (columns: 8,  gutters: 0.3, global-box-sizing: border-box, gutter-position: split)


.full_width
    width: span(5)

.three_columns
  width: span(3 of 5)
```

Adding the gutter in manually — `width: span(3 of 5) + gutter()` — or changing the gutter style — `width: span(3 of 5 after)` — both get the correct result but I'm not sure if there's a more intuitive way, other than writing my own `nested-span` function to wrap one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susy's split-gutter grid expects the parent element to be extra-wide (spanning its own gutters), and the child to be narrow (with gutters pushing it into place). That is handled automatically by the mixins if you use `nest` on the parent — e.g. `span(5 nest)`.

In your case, the child isn't actually missing a gutter — the math is all wrong. Susy is trying to calculate `span / wide-container`, but your container isn't actually wide. The error is nearly the width of a gutter, but not exactly. Adding a gutter will get you close, but it's not accurate.

The `after` syntax works perfectly because after-gutters expect a normal-width container, which is what you have. Basically, you are telling Susy to divide `span / container` instead of `span / wide-container`.

I put together [some examples on codepen](http://codepen.io/mirisuzanne/pen/b9e079ed3e903f1a25a4062ed9cb72b4?editors=1100#0) — what you have, what Susy expects, and how the `after` hack works.

Susy 2.x does not have a better way to handle this situation, because it's not an expected use-case. Susy 3.x will allow you to control the spread (narrow or wide) of a parent and child separately, to get the math you need in any situation.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I will keep an eye out for Susy 3.x.